# Subtracting two dates using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am trying to subtract 2 dates from each other but it seems that it is not subtracting properly and i am not sure what i am doing wrong here.  I am using case statement to flag as 1 if the difference between the dates are less than 90 days else flag it as 0.  But it is always flagging as 1 even if the difference between the dates are greater than 90 days.  I am PostgreSQL here and here is my case statement:

```
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM CAST(SVS_DT AS DATE) - CAST(DSCH_TS AS DATE)) <90 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FU90
```

example of the dates are here:

```
SVS_DT                         DSCH_TS
2013-03-22 00:00:00            2010-05-06 00:00:00
```

it is suppose to flag as 0 in this case but it is flagging as 1 because the difference between these 2 dates are greater than 90 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extract` of a day returns the day element of a date. Since days are always between 1 and 31, the maximum difference is 30, and cannot be larger than 90.

Subtracting `date`s returns the difference in days, as an integer. So you need only drop the `extract` calls:

```
CASE WHEN (CAST(SVS_DT AS DATE) - CAST(DSCH_TS AS DATE)) < 90 THEN 1 
                                                              ELSE 0 
     END AS FU90
```

Comment: I've also bumped into this, expecting `date` diff to be an `interval`, same as `timestamp` diff

Answer (score 1):

you can use below one:

```
CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (DATE_COLUMN_2 - DATE_COLUMN_1)) < (90*24*60*60) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FU90
```

here it returns the deference in seconds so you need to convert 90 days into seconds

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter CAST version.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SVS_DT::DATE - DSCH_TS::DATE < 90
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END 
AS FU90
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do it without using any EXTRACT or CAST keyword like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (DATE(SVS_DT)- DATE(DSCH_TS)) < 90
             THEN 1
       ELSE 0
END AS FU90
```